# For all triangle prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}m_a\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}\geq\frac{3}{4}(a+b+c)$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, triangles, geometric-inequalities

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be sides-lengths, $m_a$, $m_b$ and $m_c$ be medians-lengths

and $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be measured-angles of the triangle. Prove that:
$$m_a\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}+m_b\cos\frac{\beta}{2}+m_c\cos\frac{\gamma}{2}\geq\frac{3}{4}(a+b+c)$$

I tried Rearrangement, SOS and more.

I think, we can kill this inequality by Holder, but it's a very ugly way.

The equality "occurs" also for $a=b=1$ and $c\rightarrow2^-$, which adds problems.

Comment: A reference for SOS :(http://www.mit.edu/~evanchen/handouts/SOS_Dumbass/SOS_Dumbass.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give a hint. You can prove that for any triangle $ABC$ and point $P$ the following inequality holds: $$\sum PA.\cos(A/2) \geq p$$
To show this use Bottema's inequality for two triangles (e.g. [see here](http://gtsintsifas.com/wp-content/uploads/twotriangleinequalities.pdf)).
Use that fact that the cosines of the half-angles can be sides of a triangle and  plug them into Bottema's inequality. The RHS of the result will be not less than $p$ but buckle up for some tedious transformations.

The equality occurs in the case you mention because at one point there is a term $\sum \cos(A)$ in front of $p^2$, which is strictly greater than $1$ unless the triangle is degenerate.

In the special case when P is circumcentert this is easily proven as follows. Start from $R \geq 2r$ and use $abc=4Rrp$. Hence $2pR^2 \geq 4Rpr$ which is equivalent to $R^2(a+b+c) \geq abc $ and using the law of sines we obtain $$\sin(A)+\sin(B)+\sin(C) \geq 4\sin(A)\sin(B)\sin(C)$$
Now using the transform $A$ into $(\pi - A)/2$, etc. to get $$\sum \cos(A/2) \geq 4\prod \cos(A/2)$$. The last product of cosines is equal to $p/4R$ hence this special case follows:
$$\sum \cos(A/2) \geq p/R $$

Comment: I think your statement is wrong. Try $P$ is a circumcenter.

Comment: This would make it $\sum \cos(A/2) \geq p/R$ which looks OK to me. Remember that $p$ is semi-perimeter.

Comment: Added the proof of the special case to the answer. The general case is far too long to type.

Comment: I found mistake in my counterexample and I proved your general inequality. Thank you very much!